# Send Parameter on button link click

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am developing a system where I can send SMS to selected people based on a search. I have a dataset filled with the people, and a button that calls sendText(telephoneNo).

The code, embedded within the html, is as follows:

```
<%
for(int i = 0; i < staff; i ++)
{ %>
<h3><%= staffds.Tables["StaffAvailabilty"].Rows[i]["Name"].ToString()%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<%= staffds.Tables["StaffAvailabilty"].Rows[i]["TelephoneNo"].ToString()%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<%= staffds.Tables["StaffAvailabilty"].Rows[i]["Email"].ToString()%>
</h3>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%= staffds.Tables["StaffAvailabilty"].Rows[i]["TelephoneNo"].ToString()%>' onclick="LinkButton2_Click">Send SMS</asp:LinkButton>
<%
} %>
```

When the link is clicked, it is sending `staffds.Tables["StaffAvailabilty"].Rows[i]["TelephoneNo"].ToString()` rather than the value.

Any help would be appreciated as I've tried everything to get this working.

Comment: Instead of FOR loop you could try to use repeater and databind it to your table

Comment: The FOR loop isn't really causing any issues its the CommandArguement passing the code rather than the value, any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: @ user1162743: "For" loop in the above code is  ASP-style rendering which has its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with replacing `<%=` with `<%#` and adding `LinkButton2.DataBind()` if necessary.

Comment: I've tried the <%#, it results in an error. What do you do with the DataBind() ?

Comment: What kind of error? Also, remove `ToString()` when trying the `<%#`

Comment: It results in a Compilation Error. I have changed the code to this to see if the variable would pass better but still no luck.<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandArgument= "<%# variable%>" onclick="LinkButton2_Click">Send SMS</asp:LinkButton>